# Why does shift not work as expected in batch files with %dp0?

Tags: batch-file

What is going on here?  I'm completely baffled as to why batch is not "correctly" shifting my argument.

Here's foo.bat:

```
@echo off
echo %~dp0
shift
echo %~dp0
shift
echo %~dp0
```

Here's what happens when I run it with a param:

```
C:\Users\Public>foo bar
C:\Users\Public\
C:\Users\Public\
ECHO is off.
```

These cases are 'more expected':

```
C:\Users\Public>foo c:/this/is/some/other/path
C:\Users\Public\
c:\this\is\some\other\
ECHO is off.
```

and

```
C:\Users\Public>foo this/is/some/other/path
C:\Users\Public\
C:\Users\Public\this\is\some\other\
ECHO is off.
```

But can someone clarify what exactly is going on?  I'd figure it'd try to interpret 'bar' as a drive and path, but just come up as 'bar' in my first case...

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
ECHO params=%*
echo The drivename and PATH of the file "%~0" is %~dp0
shift
echo The drivename and PATH of the file "%~0" is %~dp0
shift
echo The drivename and PATH of the file "%~0" is %~dp0
GOTO :EOF
```

Perhaps this more expanded version would be of assistance in understanding what is taking place.

`cmd` assumes `in the current directory` if no explicit directory is provided...

Answer (score 0):

It is doing what it is supposed  to.

This has nothing to do with shift.

You are echoing the drive and path of bar. As bar isn't a file it shows you a blank drive and path.

```
 "C:\Users\User\Desktop\b.bat" c:\windows\win.ini bar
```

in bat file

```
echo %~dp1
echo %~dp2
```

Answer (score 0):

[SHIFT](https://ss64.com/nt/shift.html) shall be used with caution in scripts that rely on `%~dp0`, `%0` or similar. Consider the following example:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:start params review
echo.
echo starting ...
ECHO params=%*
echo param0=%0
echo full path is %~dp0
echo param1=%1
echo param2=%2
echo param3=%3
echo param4=%4
echo param5=%5
shift
if [%~1]==[] goto:EOF
goto :start

GOTO:EOF
C:\Program Files (x86)>test.bat a -b /c

starting ...
params=a -b /c
param0=test.bat
full path is C:\Program Files (x86)\
param1=a
param2=-b
param3=/c
param4=
param5=

starting ...
params=a -b /c
param0=a
full path is C:\Program Files (x86)\
param1=-b
param2=/c
param3=
param4=
param5=

starting ...
params=a -b /c
param0=-b
full path is C:\Program Files (x86)\
param1=/c
param2=
param3=
param4=
param5=
```

This is fine and as expected, however if we try with a different set of parameters, as soon as you have a 'path like' parameter to be shifted to position 0, things go awry:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)>test.bat a /b -c

starting ...
params=a /b -c
param0=test.bat
full path is C:\Program Files (x86)\
param1=a
param2=/b
param3=-c
param4=
param5=

starting ...
params=a /b -c
param0=a
full path is C:\Program Files (x86)\
param1=/b
param2=-c
param3=
param4=
param5=

starting ...
params=a /b -c
param0=/b
full path is C:\
param1=-c
param2=
param3=
param4=
param5=
```

The solution is as described in SS64.com to use `SHIFT /1`

```
@ECHO OFF
    SETLOCAL
    :start params review
    echo.
    echo starting ...
    ECHO params=%*
    echo param0=%0
    echo full path is %~dp0
    echo param1=%1
    echo param2=%2
    echo param3=%3
    echo param4=%4
    echo param5=%5
    shift
    if [%~1]==[] goto:EOF
    goto :start

    GOTO:EOF
C:\Program Files (x86)>test.bat a /b -c

starting ...
params=a /b -c
param0=test.bat
full path is C:\Program Files (x86)\
param1=a
param2=/b
param3=-c
param4=
param5=

starting ...
params=a /b -c
param0=test.bat
full path is C:\Program Files (x86)\
param1=/b
param2=-c
param3=
param4=
param5=

starting ...
params=a /b -c
param0=test.bat
full path is C:\Program Files (x86)\
param1=-c
param2=
param3=
param4=
param5=
```